# error during the cups operation 'client-error-document-format-not-supported'

Tags: printing

Once I add my network printer in 18.04, it shows : 
**there was an error during the cups operation 'client-error-document-format-not-supported'**

Answer (score 4):

Legacy (non-modern) printers require printer drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-all
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

Also, make sure your printer is being added in **Settings > Printers**

[image: Ubuntu printers settings]

You could also add the printer from the cups web interface at `localhost:631`.

Under administration click on **Find New Printers**. If your printer is plugged in you'd find it under the local printers.

[image: Cups add printer]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an Epson LQ-500 on ubuntu 16.04 (and DELL Optiplex 780).
I am not fully satisfied with the present installation which runs slowly (1 page prints in about 5...10mn); at least the test page seems to be correct. 
Previous install of ubuntu 16.04 on a different PC was working very well; idem for lubuntu 17 on an old laptop (ACER Aspire 1350).

The parameters listed in /etc/cups/printers.conf are:

```
...
MakeModel Epson LQ-500 Foomatic/epson (recommended)
DeviceURI parallel:/dev/lp0
...
Type 8433668
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
```

Except for the choices of MakeModel and parallel port, all parameters have default values.

I hope this will help.